# Why wont my windows service write to a file continuously?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have created a windows service that checks installed printers and updates a file currently located at "C:\App\Data\info" (no file extension) Very simple, all it does is call EnumPrinters with the correct flags and dumps PRINTER_INFO_2 to a file.

Everything works exactly as expected in Visual Studio 2010, in the "testing" project leading me to believe the issue is not in my service. As soon as I install this as a windows service it stops looping. It will run through the loop once and never again.

Code Reference:
I am using the template from here: http://www.kencotutorials.com/WindowsService.aspx
and have only changed the service class file.

Initial thoughts are either security permissions or the wait function not returning.

Edit: I have already checked the whole file system to see if its being written elsewhere and confirmed that it is not.

This is the service loop function that is called by the template.

```
void CMyService::MyServiceLoop(void)
{
    CheckPrinters(); // updates a PRINTER_INFO_2 struct with all installed printers
    WritePrinterFile(); // writes the file (i know there's no issue with the actual writing)

    Sleep(10000);
    OutputDebugString("Done sleeping");
    Return;
}
```

I have added OutputDebugString("Shell loop entered") at the start of the shell app loop.
I have also added OutputDebugString("Waiting for object") in front of the call to WaitForSingleObject()

The loop seems to hang on the WaitForSingleObject. Last message in DbgView is "Waiting for object".

Comment: What's `Sleep(10000)` doing in there?

Comment: Well initially when the service wasn't installed I needed to slow it down. I left it in because I wanted it to fire roughly every ten seconds. Could this be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of reasons.  I'd recommend you add some OutputDebugString() calls (Win32 API function) and get DbgView.exe from Microsoft to see what is going on.  Also, doesn't sound like you are doing this, but make sure you aren't writing to a mapped drive or network location, since your service most likely doesn't have access to those.

Comment: Just tried out Dbgview.exe and havnt managed to track it down, it appears to only run the loop once. Could WaitForSingleObject() cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your Windows Service, did you specify an account on the Log On tab?
http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService

The default Local System account almost surely doesn't have the rights to use the printers so be sure to set an account that can access the printers normally.

Comment: I didn't, however it will run the loop once. It accesses the printers perfectly, dumps all the info into the file and generally works exactly as expected. It just doesn't loop. Have tested logging on from my admin account and it still only runs the loop once.

Comment: Can you please post the code around the call to WaitForSingleObject that you are describing above?

Comment: I was about to and I notice a missing Do at the top of the loop, problem solved! I feel like an idiot...

Comment: The devil is usually in the details... You may want to close this question as it probably won't benefit others...